# converting to pivot table

Tags: mysql, database, pivot

Edit : Raymond Nijland has suggested and issue was at my end . i put extra group by in end

, right syntax is

```
SELECT 
    bkg.status,
count( if( bkg.status = '1', bkg.bookingId, 0 ) ) AS 'confirmed',
count( if( bkg.status = '2', bkg.bookingId, 0 ) ) AS 'Tentative'
FROM 
    tbl_booking bkg
```

thanks

---

I have table data for a table like this

[image]

i have a query

```
select bkg.status,
count(bkg.status) from tbl_booking bkg
GROUP BY 
    bkg.status;
```

that is giving results like

[image]

I want to convert that into pivot format

like

```
1 | 2 | 3 | 4
21| 57| 7 | 14
```

I tried

```
SELECT 
    bkg.status,
count( if( bkg.status = '1', bkg.bookingId, 0 ) ) AS 'confirmed',
count( if( bkg.status = '2', bkg.bookingId, 0 ) ) AS 'Tentative'
FROM 
    tbl_booking bkg
GROUP BY 
    bkg.status;
```

but that is giving me results like

[image]

If I tried to group by diffrent column like booking Id , result gone more different  . I am getting confused about which column to be placed in sum and which column to be placed in group by

please suggest

Comment: Not sure what results you are after when you want to also group by booking_id? i assume booking_id is unique within the table's data?  Pivotting status column makes sense..

Comment: oh yes. I put extra group by in end  . My bad , thanks for suggestion

Comment: "Raymond Nijland has suggested and issue was at my end . i put extra group by in end "  Oh i didn't meant that by the way.. i was thinking you also tryed this  `GROUP BY bookingId` or `GROUP BY status, bookingId` that is what mine comment was about..

Comment: yes i was , whole group by in last was not necessary , any discussion always lead to some solution ... :)

Comment: GROUP BY    bkg.bookingId . doesnt giving me desired result , yes bookigId is unique , but i want just single row of sums , any kind of group by giving me multiple rows of same kind of sum